# microsoft visual studio connected services package failed fix

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I tried to install microsoft studio community 2015,  I got so many errors and so I ran "repair " and I got the following output .Can anyone please tell me how to rectify all those errors[here I have displayed the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GB9N.png)